# Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named

Tags: python, mypy, pre-commit-hook, python-3.11, pre-commit.com

I have `mypy` pre-commit hook

```yaml
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v1.8.0
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        args:
          - --config-file=./.styleconfigs/mypy.ini
        additional_dependencies:
          [
            "types-requests",
            "types-python-dateutil",
            "types-redis",
            "types-ujson",
            "types-cachetools",
            "pydantic==2.5.3"
          ]
```

project structure

```
project_dir/
   |-- src/
   |   |-- apps/
   |   |   |-- app1/
   |   |   |   |-- __init__.py
   |   |   |   |-- mod1.py
   |   |   |-- app2/
   |   |   |   |-- __init__.py
   |   |   |   |-- mod2.py
   |   |   |-- __init__.py
   |   |-- __init__.py
   |-- .styleconfigs/
   |   |-- mypy.ini
   |-- pre-commit-config.yaml
```

**src/apps/app1/mod1.py**

```py
from apps.app2.mod2 import foo
```

I try to run `pre-commit run -a` from `project_dir` and receive errors `Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "apps.app2.mod2"`.

But when I run command `cd src && mypy --config-file ../.styleconfigs/mypy.ini .` it's work correctly.

Comment: This likely has to do with how your package is being imported. When `mypy` is running as part of the `pre-commit` hook, it's likely the installed version of your package. `mypy` **requires** that installed packages have a PEP 561 `py.typed` marker file in order to consider them for type checking, which your package does not. See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installed_packages.html#using-installed-packages

Comment: Side note: is the `__init__.py` inside `src` intentional, or a typo? If `src` is the top-level package, that would make the import `apps.app2.mod2` invalid, so it would make sense why `mypy` would complain. (`src` is a weird name for a top-level package. Usually, you put packages _inside_ `src`)

Comment: @Brian61354270 Hm. I removed `__init__.py` from `src` and now importing my "packages" is fine, but there is a problem with 3rd party libraries: 
__Cannot find implementation or stub library for module named "fastapi"__

Comment: But if I run `python -m mypy --config-file .styleconfigs/mypy.ini .` from cmd - it's fine...

Comment: I need to add some libraries to `additional_dependencies` ?

Answer (score 2):

git hooks (and therefore `pre-commit`) always run with a working directory at the root of the repository.  so you'll want to compare against that instead of `cd` into `src`

you can usually adjust mypy's options to respect your source root independent of execution through its configuration file

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Thank you. I thought so too, so this is more a question about the `mypy` configuration